# Add a sample row to a table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `table` as follows:

```
<table id="shipping">
   <tr class="Sample">
     <td>
       <input type="text">
     </td>
     <td>
        <a class="Remove">Remove</a>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And I have a hyperlink:

```
<a class="Clone">Add</a>
```

What I need to do is to add the `<tr class="Sample">` into the table each time I click on the

`<a class="Clone">`
and remove a row when I click on the `<a class="Remove">` corresponding to that row.

I tried as follows :

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Clone').click(function(){
           $('#shipping').append('.Sample');    

    });
});
</script>
```

But on clicking the hyperlink the text ".sample" gets written into the table. How can I do it ?

Comment: You want someone to code that up for you? Or have you tried something that doesn't work?

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried.

Comment: Maybe you must read something [DOM Manipulation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
$('a.Clone').click(function () {
    $('tr.Sample:last').clone().appendTo('#shipping');
})
$('#shipping').on('click', 'a.Remove:gt(0)', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="shipping">
    <tr class="Sample">
        <td>
            <input type="text">
        </td>
        <td> <a class="Remove">Remove</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table> <a class="Clone">Add</a>
```

The first part clones the input and appends it to the table. The second part handles removing the rows (leaving the top row).

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
    $('#shipping').on('click', 'a.Clone', function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault();      
     $('table#shipping').append( $(this).closest('tr').clone() );
    });
    $('#shipping').on('click', 'a.Remove', function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
     });
    });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<table id="shipping">
   <tr class="Sample">
     <td>
       <input type="text">
     </td>
     <td>
        <a class="Clone" href="#">Clone</a>
        <a class="Remove" href="#">Remove</a>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When add button is clicked call this function:

```
function myAddFunction(){
   var html = "<tr class=Sample><td><input type=text></td><td><a class=Remove>Remove</a></td></tr>"
   $('#shipping').append(html);
}
```

When remove button is clicked call this function:

```
    function myRemoveFuncion(){
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();    
    }
```

Hopre it helps.

Comment: Do not answer so easily, the author has not tried to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've just wrote a script for you

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".Remove").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
$(".Clone").on("click", function() {

var row = $('#shipping tr:last').clone(true);
row.insertAfter('#shipping tr:last');
});    


});
```

[try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/653Lhxoy/2/)